# sass/compass: nested include of all-foo-sprites mixin

Tags: extjs, sass, compass-sass

I have generate automatic sprite classes with

```
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

The import and include will magically generate classes like:

```
.icons-application_go {
  background-position: 0 -16px;
}
```

(which corresponds to icons/application_go.png file)

However, I need to include my sprites so that the resulting classes looks like this

```
.x-btn-icon.icons-application_go {
  background-position: 0 -16px;
}

.x-btn-icon.icons-delete {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

I've tried to do

```
.x-btn-icon {
  @include all-icons-sprites;
}
```

but it will result in

```
.x-btn-icon .icons-application_go {
  background-position: 0 -16px;
}

.x-btn-icon .icons-delete {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

,so selecting childs of .x-btn-icon but not elements with class="x-btn-icon icons-delete"

Right now, I have

```
.x-btn-icon.icons-add { @include icons-sprite(add); }
```

in my SASS. But I would need to do this manually for every item. I have exactly 1000 icons in this set, so this would be tedious :-)

Is there a way to loop through all icons name (like "add") and output

```
.x-btn-icon.icons-$foo { @include icons-sprite($foo); }
```

?

As per suggestion from @cram1010, I've also tried

```
@import "icons/*.png";
$icons-sprite-base-class: "&.icons-";

.x-btn-icon {
  @include all-icons-sprites;
}
```

But I got the following error:

```
Invalid CSS after "": expected selector, was "&.icons-"
  (in /Users/pasc/projects/bss-io-demo/vendor/gems/bss-io-app/app/assets/stylesheets/bss.io.app.css.scss)
```

Comment: what does your mixin 'all-icons-sprites' do?

Answer (score 4):

Following works. The key is [referencing parents selectors](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_).

Sass:

```
@mixin all-icons-sprites {
  &.icons-application_go {
    background-position: 0 -16px;
  }
  &.icons-delete {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}

.x-btn-icon {
  @include all-icons-sprites;
}
```

Is compiled to following CSS:

```
.x-btn-icon.icons-application_go {
  background-position: 0 -16px;
}

.x-btn-icon.icons-delete {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

It seems I misunderstood the question, as your mixin is automatically generated.

Have you tried of changing the `$<map>-sprite-base-class` [option for sprites in compass](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/customization-options/), so it includes the referencing parent selectors `&`?

```
$icons-sprite-base-class: "&.icons-";
```

**UPDATE 2**

For the comments, it seems that it's not possible because of compass source code. So surely a new bug should be reported to the Compass team: [github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues](http://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues)

Comment: Hey cram, thanks for the answer. The classes are automatically generated with import/include. I've edited my original questions.

Comment: I have exactly 1000 icons, so I'm looking for a automatic way without having to define all icons-* classes manually :-)

Comment: Then, I don't get what you are trying to do. But you can loop using `@each` directive: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive Hope it helps

Comment: Well, I know @each, but I need to loop through defined classes (from all-icons-sprites, which is automatically generated from the @import). Is this possible?

Comment: the correct variable name would be Invalid CSS after "": expected selector, was "&.icons-", but I'm getting Invalid CSS after "": expected selector, was "&.icons-". & doesn't seem to be possible here?

Comment: The correct variable name is $icons-sprite-base-class: "&.icons-";
because my @import is "icons/*.png". It doesn't work even with quotes with the same error (I tried it before). I've solved my original problem though, by specifying a parent elem class. It was an Ext JS specific problem. Still I'd be interested in how it could be solved as by my original question :-) I'll update my question with your proposed solution, maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: Strange... trying the statement `$icons-sprite-base-class: "&.icons-";
` in Sass online code tester give no errors: http://sass-lang.com/try.html

Comment: I guess in the case of the sass online tester, it's just some variable without any meaning. In our case it's interpreted as selector, and appearently not valid. Looking at lib/compass/sprite_importer/content.erb, the base class name is becoming a top-level selector, and & is not valid there (as there is no parent).

Comment: Well, I think it just might be not possible what I wanted. (It's not a big problem because as I said, I found another solution meanwhile. 
 Although the question isn't answered, I will grant you the bounty for being very helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome @PaulSchyska. It seems then it could only be solved changing compass source code... You could maybe open a bug in compass: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues Thanks for the bounty and good luck!